# How to change index name in multiindex groupby object with condition?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I need to change 0 level index ('Product Group') of pandas groupby object, based on conditions (sum of related values in column 'Sales').
Since code is very long and some files are needed, I`ll copy output.
the last string of code is:

```
tdk_regions = tdk[['Region', 'Sales', 'Product Group']].groupby(['Product Group', 'Region']).sum()
```

###The output will be like this

```
Product Group                   Region  Sales
ALUMINUM & FILM CAPACITORS BG   America 7.425599e+07
                                China   2.249969e+08
                                Europe  2.404613e+08
                                India   6.034134e+07
                                Japan   7.667371e+06
... ... ...
TEMPERATURE&PRESSURE SENSORS BG Europe  1.308471e+08
                                India   3.077273e+06
                                Japan   2.851744e+07
                                Korea   1.309189e+06
                                OSEAN   1.258075e+07
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `MultiIndex.rename`:

```py
df.index.rename("New Name", level=0, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                             Sales
New Name                      Region              
ALUMINUM & FILM CAPACITORS BG America   74255990.0
                              China    224996900.0
                              Europe   240461300.0
                              India     60341340.0
                              Japan      7667371.0
```

Comment: This is direct rename without conditions. My question was whether it1s possible to change index, based on conditions (total amount in column 'Sales')

Comment: @Vladislav Maybe I don't understand. Do you want to insert `Total` row in each `Product Group` ?

Comment: It could be the way, but  finally I only need change name of index(0), based on total sum of sales. E.g. Total < x  df.index.rename("Other", level=0, inplace=True).

Comment: @Vladislav Can you please edit your question and put there short example input/expected output?

Comment: I have no idea how to logically put condition in this case. 
Something like 
df.loc[df['Sales'].sum() <x,  df.index.get_level_values(0)] = 'Other'...
But this is obviously incorrect